# Tkinter keyrelease event inserting new line while keypress doesn't

Tags: python, tkinter

In the below code, If I use `KeyRelease` to bind events, then on hitting `return` key results in an unwanted new line in the text widget. However If I use `KeyPress` to bind events, then no new line is inserted.

Can some one please explain the differnce between the two and why I am observing such an behavior. Any pointers to refernce material would be appreciated.

```
from Tkinter import *

def getCommand(*args):
    global text
    text.insert(END, "\n")
    text.insert(END, "command>")
    return 'break'

def handle_keyrelease(event):
    if event.keysym == "Return":
        getCommand()
        return 'break'

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert(END,"command>")
text.focus()
text.bind("<KeyRelease>", handle_keyrelease) # Change the event handler to see the difference

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hitting and releasing a key on a text widget, `<KeyPress>` is raised, then the text widget is updated, then `<KeyRelease>` is raised. You can easily verify this yourself, using a little demo program handling both events.

When binding to `<KeyPress>`, you can prevent the event from being propagated to other handlers (and thus the one that updates the text widget) by returning the string`"break"` from your event handler function.

If you bind to `<KeyRelease>`, it's already too late to prevent the insertion of the newline, since at that point in time the text has already been updated.

Note that, in your example, you could also handle `<KeyPress-Return>` or simply `<Return>` instead of checking for `event.keysym == "Return"`.